# Core Data Migration Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

My app shipped with data model 1.  I just created a data model 2 and tested on my device and it migrated fine.  I just noticed that I made a mistake with the attribute so I need to create a new data model 3.  So then can I delete data model 2 after I migrate my device to 3?  Because data Model 2 never hit the app store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

As long as you make sure that the migration between model 1 and model 3 is still suitable for migration but that's easy to test - just download your app from the app store (creating model 1 on your phone) and then run your latest app from XCode and watch it migrate :)